# $C:W\to Z$ and $A:V\to W$. Prove $\| CA\|_{V,Z}\leq \|C\|_{W,Z} \|A\|_{V,W}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have been trying to prove this result(consistency) using the supremum definition and an elementary property of the operator norm as below. 
$$
\|A\|_{V,W}=
\sup_{\mathbf{v} \in{V} }\|\cdot \| , \quad \|A(\mathbf{v})\| \leq \|A\|_{V,W} \|\mathbf{v}\|_{V}  $$
This is my ATTEMPT at the  proof
$$
\begin{align}
\|CA\|_{V,Z}&=\sup_{\mathbf{v} \in{V} } \{\frac{\|C(A(\mathbf{v}))\|_{Z}}{\|\mathbf{v}\|_V}\}
\leq  \sup_{\mathbf{v} \in{V} } \{\frac{\|C\|_{W,Z}\|(A(\mathbf{v}))\|_{W}}{\|\mathbf{v}\|_V}\}
\\ &
\leq  \sup_{\mathbf{v} \in{V} } \{\frac{\|C\|_{W,Z}\|A\|_{V,W}\|\mathbf{v}\|_{V}}{\|\mathbf{v}\|_V}\}
\\ & 
\leq  \sup_{\mathbf{v} \in{V} }\{\|C\|_{W,Z}\|A\|_{V,W}\}
\\ & 
\leq  \sup_{\mathbf{v} \in{V} }\{\|C\|_{W,Z}\}\sup_{\mathbf{v} \in{V} }\{\|A\|_{V,W}\} 
\end{align}
$$

I am stuck. The reason is because the last line is a supremum. How do I get by without the supremum? (Or have I gone too far through the inequality). Another way that may be useful is to try to evaluate from the second inequality line as below.

$$
\begin{align}
\|CA\|_{V,Z} &=
\sup_{\mathbf{v} \in{V} } \{\frac{\|C(A(\mathbf{v}))\|_{Z}}{\|\mathbf{v}\|_V}\}
\\ & 
\leq  \sup_{\mathbf{v} \in{V} } \{\frac{\|C\|_{W,Z}\|(A(\mathbf{v}))\|_{W}}{\|\mathbf{v}\|_V}\}
\\ & 
\leq \sup_{\mathbf{v} \in{V} }\{\|C\|_{W,Z}\}\sup_{\mathbf{v} \in{V} } \{\frac{\|(A(\mathbf{v}))\|_{W}}{\|\mathbf{v}\|_V}\} 
\\ & =\sup_{\mathbf{v} \in{V} }\{\|C\|_{W,Z}\}\|A\|_{V,W} 
\end{align}
$$

The problem with this way, is that I am still stuck with supremum of $\|C\|_{W,V}$. How do I get rid of the supremum on $\|C\|_{W,V}$?

Comment: I've made some formatting changes to your questions; please take note for future reference.

Comment: Also, see [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/81360) for a tutorial on mathematical typesetting (using MathJax).

Answer (score 0):

Your proof is fine; you're seeing a problem where there is none.

Note that you're taking the supremum over $v \in V$, and that $\|C\|_{W,V} \geq 0$ is a "constant" with respect to $v$.  In particular, we can always say
$$
\sup_{v \in V}\left\{\|C\|_{W,V}\,f(v)\right\} = 
\|C\|_{W,V} \sup_{v \in V}\left\{f(v)\right\}
$$
for any $f:V \to \Bbb R$.